# What is Lazar's official position?

Tags: manhattan

Lazar is a (Russian-origin?) scientist who operates off-base at some location called "Icarus outpost". He is a bit of a mad scientist and seems to run his own experiments.

What is his official position? (Why is he allowed to operate off-base? Why does he seem to not be subject to the usual strict security measures?)

Comment: I re-watched Season 1 of the show recently, and I must confess that this wasn't entirely clear to me either last time I watched it or this time around.  I got the sense that he was more of a quartermaster or a technician who was specifically in charge of the explosives supply, rather than a scientist or engineer directly working on the bomb.  And as far as why he's off-base, well, he had a lot of explosives in his cabin.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Frank says he called Albert Einstein who told him Lazar was "a good scientist" and "could be trusted". Lazar says, "Einstein was wrong. I'm not a scientist. I'm an engineer." // Also, with all the explosives, that might explain being off-base, but not why there is no security---it seems like anyone can just drive up to Lazar's home where all the explosives are (as Frank does) without any security around.

Comment: The real-life Los Alamos site was 54,000 acres, or about 84 square miles.  There are also scenes elsewhere in the series that imply that the restricted area is quite large, e.g., the episode where Frank browbeats a guard into letting some Native Americans past the gate so that they can perform a ceremony for a dead relative at a holy site that they wouldn't otherwise be allowed to get to (and which looked pretty deserted when we saw it.)  So it seems plausible to me that Lazar's cabin is still in a restricted area, just not anywhere near the main townsite/lab.